# removeOnNewIntentListener not working in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my fragment, I assign a new intent listener and add it to the activity using `addOnNewIntentListener`, but when going back from this fragment, and because in another fragment I have this kind of `listener`, when `onNewIntent` calls then this below fragment `callback` is called, even though I removed it on `onPause` using `removeOnNewIntentListener`

```kotlin
private var intentListener: ((Intent) -> Unit)? = null

...

override fun onPause() {
    intentListener?.run {
         activity?.removeOnNewIntentListener(this)
    }
    super.onPause()
}
    
private fun initListeners() {
    intentListener = {
    // ...
    }
    intentListener?.run { activity?.addOnNewIntentListener(this)}
}
```

Comment: When is initListeners called? And from where?

Comment: it is called on onViewCreated of fragment it is initialized

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see that it is actually being called?

Comment: yeap, it causing crash because of the ui interaction, (fragment not atteched to activity)